# What domains of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the property that $H^1(\Omega)=H^1_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation

i wonder what are sufficient conditions on an unbounded domain of $R^n$ called $\Omega$ to get :
$C_c^\infty (\Omega)$ dense in $H^1 (\Omega)$ ?
where $C_c^\infty$ stands for the set of functions with compact support, infinitely differentiable.
all the best,

C.

Comment: If you have a minimum of regularity for the boundary, this won't hold, as it forces continuous functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ to vanish on $\partial \Omega$. I wonder what can be said for $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, though.

Comment: Alright let's begin for instance with an infinite strip in $R^2$, something like $[-L,L] \times \mathbb R$ ? or more generally an (open) unbounded domain, bounded in one direction.

Comment: Such a domain will always have $H^1_0(\Omega)\subsetneq H^1(\Omega)$. That's for the reason I wrote above.

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but this should be true if and only if the complement of $\partial \Omega$ has zero $2$-capacity. In particular, the complement must have empty interior (though this is not sufficient).

Comment: Some guys also define Sobolev spaces for closed $\Omega$, then you always have $H^1(\Omega) = H_0^1(\Omega)$, since $C_c^\infty(\Omega) = C^\infty(\Omega)$.